# How to draw polygon in HERE Map from polygon data stored in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, here-api

I have a polygon data stored in mysql column "poligon" with structure like this 
`(lat, long)(lat,long)`...

> '(-6.811408423530006, 110.85068956017494)(-6.811770629167109,
>   110.85174098610878)(-6.81129656585151, 110.85196629166603)(-6.810718634097109, 110.85200116038322)(-6.8106946645623, 110.85195824503899)(-6.811046217619413, 110.85130110383034)'

how to enter this data to polygon code HERE Map Js API bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; background: grey" />
  <script  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" >


/**
  * Adds a polygon to the map
  *
  * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
*/
function addPolygonToMap(map) {
  var geoStrip = new H.geo.Strip(
[52, 13, 100, 48, 2, 100, 48, 16, 100, 52, 13, 100], 'values lat lng alt'
  );
  map.addObject(
    new H.map.Polygon(geoStrip, {
      style: {
        fillColor: '#FFFFCC',
        strokeColor: '#829',
        lineWidth: 8
      }
    })
  );
}



/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  app_id: 'DemoAppId01082013GAL',
  app_code: 'AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg',
  useCIT: true,
  useHTTPS: true
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:52, lng:5},
  zoom: 5
});

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);


// Now use the map as required...
addPolygonToMap(map);
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how to replace this data bellow with my polygon data structure (lat, long)(lat, long)...

```
new H.geo.Strip(
[52, 13, 100, 48, 2, 100, 48, 16, 100, 52, 13, 100], 'values lat lng alt'
  );
```

sorry i'm newbie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are retrieving the data for the polygon as a string on the javascript side, you should be able to use simple String manipulation.

```js
var latLonString="(-6.811408423530006, 110.85068956017494)(-6.811770629167109, 110.85174098610878)(-6.81129656585151, 110.85196629166603)(-6.810718634097109, 110.85200116038322)(-6.8106946645623, 110.85195824503899)(-6.811046217619413, 110.85130110383034)";
   //to remove first '(' and last ')'
   latLonString=latLonString.substring(1,latLonString.length -2);
   // get individual coordinates
   var latLonValues=latLonString.split("\)\(");
   var finalArray=[];
   for(i=0;i<latLonValues.length;i++){
    var latLonSperated=latLonValues[i].split(",");
    finalArray.push(parseFloat(latLonSperated[0]));
    finalArray.push(parseFloat(latLonSperated[1]));
    // no altitude
    finalArray.push(0);
   }
   var polystrip1 = new H.geo.Strip(finalArray);
   var polygon1 = new H.map.Polygon(polystrip1);
   map.addObject(polygon1);
```